# azure functions Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I am writing an http trigger azure function which validates a Json and stores it in a Database. Multiple clients(other servers)call this function.
Azure function app provides different authorization levels(function, admin) which issues one password which can be used by all the clients and secure the function app. I would like to know if we can issue different passwords for different clients or implement authorization protocols like Oauth or similar for more security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an authentication way for you to refer, you could try to configure `Authentication / Authorization` in the **Platform features** in your function app.

You could follow the steps below.

1. At first, go to **Integrate** of your Httptrigger, set `Authorization level` to `Anonymous`.

[image]

2.Got to `Authentication / Authorization`, in this scenario, for example, I configure it with `Log in with Azure Active Directory` and Save the configuration, refer to the screenshot.

[image]

3.Then go to the **Azure Active Directory** in the portal, you could find your app registration.

[image]

4.Configure the `homepage` in the **Manifest** with your **Httptrigger URL** (you could get it with `</> Get function URL` in your Httptrigger), save the manifest.

[image]

5.Try to log in the HttpTrigger with the url like `https://yourfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/yourhttptrigger?xxxxx` in the browser, it will redirect to the AAD login page, use the AAD account to log in, then could see your HttpTrigger.

[image]

[image]

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

Comment: Thanks Joy Wang for the example, I would like to call my function from a client such as Postman, when Im trying I get 401 Response Code with You do not have permission to view this directory or page message. Do we have to do it differently from clients like postman(Im using POST and GET methods)

Comment: @Sushruth This is normal,  if you use the httptrigger url in the postman, it will not redirect to the auth url, for using postman,  you could refer to this link: [Using postman with Azure AD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devkeydet/2016/03/22/using-postman-with-azure-ad/).